# Stripe webhook run firebase cloud function when a user subscribed to a subscription plan

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I use the stripe extension for firebase. I have already set up payment. Now I want to make a change to a firebase document when a user successfully subscribes to a plan.

In addition to the stripe customer collection that is automatically created by the stripe extension, I have created a user collection in firebase that stores things like email and user role. When the user has successfully subscribed, I want to change the role field in the document named as the user's uid in the users collection.

Which approach should I choose? What does Firebase's cloud function look like?

Comment: Your question is broad and will likely need to be narrowed down to get quality answers from the community. In general from the Stripe side you'll likely want to set up a webhook endpoint that will have Events sent to it as actions are triggered in your Stripe account. What have you tried so far, and what problems did those approaches run into that you're trying to solve for?

Answer (score 1):

> Stripe webhook run firebase cloud function when a user subscribed to a
> subscription plan. What does Firebase's cloud function look like?

You should use an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). Here is a skeleton that you need to beef up according to your needs.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    // Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
    return cors(req, res, async () => {

        try {

            const payload = req.body; // The payload posted by the Stripe when calling the webhook

            // Example: How to update the user doc  
            const userID = payload.xxx;
            const userDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userID}`);

            await userDocRef.update( {role: ....});

            res.status(200).end();

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            return res.status(500).end(error.message);
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: how can i check if the webhook is the ```customer.subscription.created```webhook? Im pretty new to this webhook thing sorry if its obvious.

Comment: Stripe sends the event data in the request body. Each event is structured as an Event object with a type, id, and related Stripe resource nested under data. As explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events), "if you create a new subscription for a customer, you will receive both a `customer.subscription.created` event and a `charge.succeeded event`". I advise to give a try and to log the the object returned by the Stripe webhook call in the body.

Comment: Hey @LikeroBayer, did you have the opportunity to try the proposed approach?